# Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 doesn't suspend

Tags: nvidia, suspend, power-management, 15.10, ubuntu-gnome

I'm having an issue with Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 (also had the same issue with 15.04 before making a clean install of 15.10).

When closing the laptop lid, the computer shuts down instead of suspending.
*EDIT: It seems to suspend properly, but shuts down when trying to resume.*

The tweak-tool settings are set to suspend whether power is connected or not.

I'm not sure what relevant information to provide, but I'm using a "Lenovo Flex 2" with nvidia graphics card drivers, no external monitors connected. (I've read about similar problems with external monitors)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you open a terminal and issue the command `systemctl suspend` does the computer suspend properly?

Comment: I'm afraid not, it's exactly the same with both systemctl and dbus suspend commands from the terminal. I realize now that it does in fact suspend, however it doesn't resume properly. It seems to crash or shut down, then boots from scratch.

I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: [This Ubuntu Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend) may help in determining what the problem is.

Comment: Having the same problem with asus ux303ua,but only when running ob battery